# How to reduce Hipparcos catalog star coordinates to another Epoch?

Tags: astrometry, hipparcos

Hipparcos catalog lists star equatorial coordinates (RA,Decl).
The coordinates are 1991.25 positions on ICRS reference frame (epoch J2000).

According to Astronomical Algorithms (J. Meeus) the following
corretions must be applied when reducing the coordinates to another epoch.

Precession, Aberration, Nutation, Proper Motion.

In this case we have two base dates. The 1991.25 positions and the 2000 Equinox/Equator.
Is it correct to calculate the corrections in relation to the dates below ?

1.Precession- relation to J2000.0

2.Aberration- in relation to J2000.0

3.Nutation- in relation to J2000.0

4.Proper Motion- in relation to 1991.25